# Google maps Multipoint not rendering when there is more number of markers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

Multipoint geometry in google maps is failing to render markers properly when there is more number of markers.
[Google maps Multi point rendering](http://jsfiddle.net/ecntmv69/)

```
 var mapProp = {
    center: x,
    zoom: 5
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

map.data.addGeoJson(data);
map.data.setStyle(function (feature) {
     return /** @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */({
    icon: {
      url: feature.getProperty('icon'),
      icon: feature.getProperty('icon'),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(40, 40), // scaled size 16 px
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(20, 25) // anchor
    },
    size: '10px'
  });
});
```

`data` is geojson Feature collection array.

Answer (score 0):

It looks only the centre is wrong :) look at this

```
var x = new google.maps.LatLng(35.38904996691167, 75.377197265625);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k0pzdg9f/1/

Comment: It is working fine with one or two Multipoint geometry features.When I give set of geometry Multipoint features not working fine.

Comment: Not working fine, as in, what is happening? Aren't those the geometry feature points which are visible in the map?

Comment: Those geometry features are visible but those icons are becoming clumpsy and they are breaking other icons.SVG also breaking.

Comment: suryapratap the feature points are becoming like as in fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/jLvq3opr/

Comment: I dont think it has anything to do with number of feature poins, it is your image which it is not able to scale properly, try using something from http://kml4earth.appspot.com/icons.html#shapes